# xpath return nodes which don't contain a certain node at all

Tags: html, xml, xpath

I'm using xpath to locate html tags. I have a table with 5 rows and I want to select rows based on the class in some of the table data tags inside the table rows.

```
<table class="layoutDataDefinitionTable grid-row-table">
    <thead/>
    <tbody>
        <tr id="row_0"/>
            <td data-dojo-attach-point="_iconNode"/>
            <td class="dgrid-cell-padding dgrid-no-left"/>
            <td class="dgrid-cell-padding"/>
            <td class="dgrid-cell-padding"/>
            <td class="dgrid-cell-padding"/>
            <td class="dgrid-cell-padding"/>
            <td class="dgrid-cell-padding"/>
        <tr id="row_1">
            <td data-dojo-attach-point="_iconNode" class="arrowDown"/>
            <td class="dgrid-cell-padding dgrid-no-left"/>
            <td class="dgrid-cell-padding"/>
            <td class="dgrid-cell-padding"/>
            <td class="dgrid-cell-padding"/>
            <td class="dgrid-cell-padding"/>
            <td class="dgrid-cell-padding"/>
        <tr id="row_2">
            <td data-dojo-attach-point="_iconNode"/>
            <td class="dgrid-cell-padding dgrid-no-left dgrid-cell-indent"/>
            <td class="dgrid-cell-padding"/>
            <td class="dgrid-cell-padding"/>
            <td class="dgrid-cell-padding"/>
            <td class="dgrid-cell-padding"/>
            <td class="dgrid-cell-padding"/>
        <tr id="row_3">
            <td data-dojo-attach-point="_iconNode" class="arrowDown"/>
            <td class="dgrid-cell-padding dgrid-no-left"/>
            <td class="dgrid-cell-padding"/>
            <td class="dgrid-cell-padding"/>
            <td class="dgrid-cell-padding"/>
            <td class="dgrid-cell-padding"/>
            <td class="dgrid-cell-padding"/>
        <tr id="row_4">
            <td data-dojo-attach-point="_iconNode" class="arrowDown"/>
            <td class="dgrid-cell-padding dgrid-no-left"/>
            <td class="dgrid-cell-padding"/>
            <td class="dgrid-cell-padding"/>
            <td class="dgrid-cell-padding"/>
            <td class="dgrid-cell-padding"/>
            <td class="dgrid-cell-padding"/>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to select the table rows without a table data with the class arrowDown and without the class dgrid-cell-padding dgrid-no-left dgrid-cell-indent. I've tried doing this:

```
$x("//table[contains(@class, 'layoutDataDefinitionTable grid-row-table')]//tbody//tr//td[not(contains(@class, 'dgrid-cell dgrid-cell-padding dgrid-no-left dgrid-cell-indent')) and not(contains(@class, 'arrowDown'))]/..");
```

But that just returns all the rows because every row has a td which doesn't contain both of those classes. I want it to return row 0 only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can move your predicate to the `tr`, and check all `td` children to see whether or not they all meet the criteria of not containing the desired classes:
`//table[contains(@class, 'layoutDataDefinitionTable grid-row-table')]/tbody/tr[not(contains(td/@class, 'dgrid-cell-padding dgrid-no-left dgrid-cell-indent')) and not(contains(td/@class, 'arrowDown'))]`

this will return only the `tr` with id `row_0`.